# What is happening with the Google API service today?

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api, google-api-client

Hello Google API support,

Supposedly you're monitoring this forum and helping developers.

We run a sync service and use various Google APIs to sync data for our users.
Today we've had a ton of errors from the Google Contacts API.

Could someone explain what is happening? It seems like problems on Google side.
Will this be fixed soon?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
 <error>
  <domain>GData</domain>
  <code>badRequest</code>
  <internalReason>Bad Request</internalReason>
 </error>
</errors>
```

Caused by: com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:602) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:1.47.1]
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:1.47.1]
        at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:676) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:1.47.1]
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1034) ~[gdata-core-1.0-1.47.1.jar:1.47.1]

Comment: http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status isn't showing any world wide outages.  But that doesn't mean that there couldn't be an issue relative to your area.   I checked Google+ as well no other reports of issues that I could find.  These errors normally resolve by them selves quite quickly.

Comment: Hi DalmTo, thank you for taking a look. We sync data for hundreds of Google users using various APIs and yesterday we started getting a ton of 'Bad request' errors for many of them so it's not just one or two instances. The errors still continue. I can provide more specific details of the mailboxes but in a private way. Let me know if you could help here. Thanks -Alexey

Comment: By the way, that app status monitor does not show the Contacts API with which we're having problems. -A

Comment: After experimenting more with the API it looks like Google sends this 400 Bad Request error sort of like a means of rate limiting because if we wait a little and try again the request goes through. Too bad the API does not return the appropriate 503 status code.